# botocore.exceptions.ClientError (InvalidAccessKeyId)

Tags: django, docker, spaces

I am new to docker and in our dev env, we have S3 access key id and AWS secret access key. We are using the digital ocean spaces to offload our dev env static files. We need to run the collect static command manually to update the media and static files. The whole process was working fine for the last couple of months but I am recently facing this error. After some research, I updated the Acess key id and AWS secret access key but this error remains the same. Can anyone please help me with this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBb29.png)

Comment: Seems like the image didn't attach correctly. here is the error message 
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: Unknown